# Is modifying a metaclass from an external module possible?

Tags: python, metaprogramming

Let's have an external module called `fields.py` with a metaclass `FieldModelMetaclass` which alters class `FieldModel`:

```
# module fields.py
class FieldModelMetaclass(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        # code to alter class creation

class FieldModel(object):
    __metaclass__ = FieldModelMetaclass
    print 'run at parse time BEFORE metaclass applies'

# module consumer.py
import fields

def adjust_metaclass_new(cls, name, bases, attrs):
  # do an extra work on class `cls' and attributes `attrs'

# Is somehow possible from here alter `FieldModelMetaclass.__new__`
# by injection of adjust_metaclass_new to modify FieldModel
# before it gets instantiated ?
mymodel = fields.FieldModel()
```

As far as I know, metaclass of a class takes an effect at <del>compile</del> runtime so at the moment when I do import a module where is defined, class is already affected.

How can I intercept effect of metaclass at class creation from an external module ?

Comment: The metaclass takes effect *at runtime*, not compile time. However, since it is being used *in the same module*, you cannot intercept the metaclass before it is already being used when loading the class statement.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh yes I see it now :) Of course :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters So am I left to inject `Class.__new__` method so it would be called at each Class instantiation ?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks. Is there some performance penalty contrary to direct modification of metaclass definition ?

Comment: @DavidUnric: that depends on what you are actually trying to *do* here. Running extra Python code each time an instance is created is obviously going to 'cost' more than running code once each time a class is created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you cannot easily intercept the use of the MetaClass. The `FieldModelMetaclass.__new__` method is called right after the `class FieldModel` body completes, when importing the module (so at *runtime*, not compile time).

You could in theory use a [`sys.setrace()` hook](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) to inject additional Python code after the metaclass has been created but before the `class` statement executes, but this way madness lies.

Another theoretical option would be to parse the module source code, rewrite it (using the [`ast` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html)), but again, this way more madness lies.

You can just add a `__call__` method to the metaclass or a `__new__` method to each class created with the metaclass, if all you wanted was to intercept creation of new instances:

```
import fields

def metaclass__call__(cls, *args, **kw):
    instance = super(FieldModelMetaclass, cls).__call__(*args, **kw)
    # do something to the instance
    return instance

FieldModelMetaclass.__call__ = metaclass__call__
```

If your goal was to alter the way `FieldModelMetaclass` produces the class objects, then your best option is to just alter the class objects again after import. You can always add more attributes to the class, or replace the class with a different one using your own metaclass.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the answer. I can't imagine use of `settrace` in production code as it would significantly slow runtime speed as tracefunc gets called at each expression. Parsing source with AST looks like even greater madness ;)  Good idea with `.__call__` method, similar use as `__new__` but separates things.

Comment: @DavidUnric: and has the added advantage that you can set it on the metaclass and have *all* classes that derive from it use it.

Comment: As a side note, here Ruby gets an upper hand as reopening and modifying **any** class (unlike Python's built-in/extension) is unlimited and simple.

Comment: @DavidUnric: it is unlimited and simple in Python too though. What you are asking for is to alter the factory before it spits out its product, which here is hard to intercept. But we can alter the final product quite easily. :-)

Comment: Some answers are just art at its finest!